# How can I program PIC16F84A microcontroller using assembly language?

Tags: assembly, pic

I need help on how to program a PIC16F84A using assembly language.

The task I want to achieve is to program the MicroController to turn on an LED using assembly language. I have read the datasheet of the microcontroller and I don't understand anything yet about it.

I am new to assembly language, I have read all the free ebooks available online, but I still find it difficult to program a micro controller. I know I have to follow the instructions set for the microcontroller, but I don't seem to know how to start.

Below is the code i was able to write;

```
;***************************************************
; Program: Power on LED using PIC16F84A MCU        *
; Author: Obiora Micheal O                         *
; Date: 11 November 2016                           *
; Notes : Write an assembly language program to    *
; power on an LED using PIC16F84A Microcontroller  *
;***************************************************

; Assembly source line config statements
 PROCESSOR 16F84A
#include "p16F84A.inc"

; CONFIG
; __config 0xFFF7
 __CONFIG _FOSC_EXTRC & _WDTE_ON & _PWRTE_ON & _CP_OFF

org 0x00    ; reset vector
start   ; goto the beginning of the main program
```

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, Micheal.   This question is broad enough that it's off-topic.

Comment: How is the question broad and off topic? Please just help, I have been on this problem for 3 days now and no where to get help from.

Comment: "Please just" read the rules of the road I just posted.   You will not get good results here otherwise.  Your title does not indicate your specific problem, you don't post enough specific information for anyone to begin to answer your question, you don't show us your code / what you've tried, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Specific questions are on-topic;  "how does assembly work" is not.   Get an assembly programming textbook or find an online tutorial.

Comment: I have not tried any code because I don't know what to write. pls take a look at the image I just uploaded. That is all I can do for now.

Comment: You should also know that we don't post code in images here, people will downvote you for that.   Put the code directly into the question with the proper formatting.   Again though, this is not a place to get an "intro to programming" in general.

Comment: (Maybe google search for "intro to PIC assembly"?   I found three good-looking resources in about 10 seconds that way.)

Comment: I guess you don't understand my question that is all. I am not asking for intro to programming. Programming in hardware is different from programming in software. I need to write a code to the microcontroller to enable it do what I want. I don't understand the instruction sets and how to go about it.

Comment: I totally understand your question.  I program both AVR and PIC microcontrollers.   It's still:  off-topic.

Comment: I believe you know what am talking about, maybe you just don't want to help. the ebooks I downloaded online, when i compile the codes in it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to start with that particular microcontroller? The chip you mention is a very old part and hard to program as you will need a special "download cable".

I would recommend an easier device (that still can be programmed in assembler).
For instance one of those Arduino development boards. You can at least plug those right into your computer's USB-port.

Also, have a look at this page:
http://www.voti.nl/swp/n_index.html

Some examples here:
http://www.boondog.com/tutorials/pic16F84/pic16f84.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have the hardware, I designed the circuit already using Proteus, I need to simulate to know if my circuit is working. Before simulation can work, the mcu must be programmed. Lecturer will only accept assembly language and not C.

Comment: I have a MPLAB IDE, I don't know how to set the bsf and bcf of the mcu, I don't know how to declare the variables, I can set the configuration bits, the header directives, but after that, I am stucked because I don't know the next step to follow.

Comment: First, try creating a new project in MPLAB.

As for the source code, copy over the assembly listing from the simplest example you can find on the internet. For instance the BoonDog site mentioned in my answer has source code for switching on a few LEDs on PORT B. 

Try to generate a HEX file from the project. This is where MPLAB translates your assembly code into a binary file the PIC16 can understand and load.

Finally, load the HEX file in your simulated MCU. I presume your Proteus software has some MPLAB driver or plug-in to make this possible.